# Call function with same arguments as parent

Tags: javascript

I've got a lot of function that act as an intermediate entry-point for other functions (i.e functions that just call other functions).

- How can I call the inner function with the *same* arguments as the parent function *without respecifying them*?

  ```
  var foo = function(arg1, arg2) {
    fooBar(argumentsOfFoo);  
  }
  ```
- A possible solution is passing arrays but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```
var foo = function(arg1, arg2) {
  fooBar.apply(this, arguments);  
}
```

In modern versions of Javascript, you can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function foo(...args) {
  fooBar(...args);  
}
```

Comment: Added rest parameter option for modern Javascript.